# Looking for a gentle intro to Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Does anyone know of any gentle, introductory books to LA that assume little prerequisites, even in the way of vectors and matrices? I want something that will give intuition and reasonable proofs, and will provide enough background for something like computational neuroscience. I do not know calculus, but plan on learning that in tandem with/after LA. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try these books:

- [Introduction to Linear Algebra](http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/#toc) by Strang.
- [Linear Algebra and its Applications](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/lay/) by Lay.

Comment: I recommend Strang's book, it has FFT examples which are useful for signal analysis

Comment: Lay is a good choice given the background and preparation of the student here. He might do well with Anton alternatively. There are so many of these sort of linear books really.

Comment: Lay abounds with notes for applications of LA, a very good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not a superb first introduction, I have to recommend Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler.

Comment: What background must I have to use it as a first book?

Comment: Axler makes some nonstandard choices about presentation and it seems unmotivated without the maturity to understand his philosophy. The only thing you'd need in my opinion is mathematical maturity and motivation, but I know I personally started developing those in my first Linear Algebra course.

Comment: Does it cover the basic definitions and operations of vectors and matrices (e.g. what they are, how to add, subtract, etc.)?